# i want to find all the record against second highest salary in table and there many employee with second highest salary how to do that

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find all the records with the second highest salary in the table.  There are many such employees, how do I do that?

Table: Employee

```
ID    salary      emp_name   emp_address                           
1     400         A          abc
2     800         B          def 
3     300         C          hjs
4     400         D          teuu
5     400         E          kakn
6     400         E          kssj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dense_rank` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) rn
  From your_table t) t
Where rn = 2
```

If you are on lower version of mysql in which windows functions are not allowed then you can use corelated query as follows:

```
Select t.*
  From your_table t
 Where 1 = (select count(distinct tt.salary)
             From your_table tt
            Where tt.salary > t.salary)
```

Comment: can you explain more about the above query I am not getting the query

Comment: First query gives the rank to the salary in descending order and we are fetching the record for which rank is 2. (for same salary, same rank is given using dense_rank). -------- Second query, fincd the records for which we have only 1 salary available which is higher that current record. It simply means that current record is second highest

Answer (score 0):

You might find it simple enough to do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.salary = (select distinct t2.salary
                  from t t2
                  order by t2.salary desc
                  limit 1 offset 1
                 );
```